# Is it possible to have different profiles/usernames across community sites?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, linked-accounts, privacy, multiple-accounts

I have a couple of sites that I have been using for a while and use in a professional context.

However, there are other community sites I would like to be more active on with asking for help from others - however with all stack exchange sites interlinked I'm reluctant to do so.

Is there anyway for handling this without having to create a second account and switching between them?

Comment: Yes you can set your display name separately for each site if that's what you wanted to know... but the accounts remain interlinked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each site's account is separate in that you can have a different name, profile information etc. However, by default all your other accounts will appear in the "Accounts" section.

However, you can hide accounts. Select the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, then the "Hide Communities" option:

[image]

Then on the list of sites click the "Hide" button:

[image]

This doesn't create two lists (e.g. "professional" and "hobby") but would hide the "non-professional" sites from your public profile. As the page says it doesn't stop people finding your accounts on these sites.

Comment: That's great thank you very much - one question by extension....of the public communities I can only see the first 12; anything beyond this I can't do 'next page' and have to start typing a substring of a particular community I'm looking to remove from my public profile. I would think it would make sense for members to be able to see their full list without guessing `a` `e` `i` `o` `u`