# How can I log into two different accounts on two different sites now (July 2015)?

Tags: support, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

There has been some recent behavior change on SE (around July 2015).  I have two accounts I use, one Google openId based for one set of sites (call it Account-A) and another SE login based for a different set of sites (Account-B).  Used to be that I could be logged into one set of sites with the first user and a different set with the other users.

But now I am logged in with the Account-A on Site-1.  When I go to one of the sites I use the other account for and click "log in" under the SE menu, I go to a page where I only have an option to confirm creation of an account based on my Google login.  It does not present a way to log in with an SE account.

[image]

How can I log in with my other account here?

(and before you flag this as a duplicate, please ensure the other question is recent enough and that the answer is relevant.  This behavior has definitely morphed over the years... and I am having trouble finding something that is relevant.  For instance this question [How to log in to SE sites using a second account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213282/how-to-log-in-to-se-sites-using-a-second-account) simply points out how to merge the accounts which is NOT what I want  .  This question [Is it possible to have different profiles/usernames across community sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257398/is-it-possible-to-have-different-profiles-usernames-across-community-sites) talks about presenting different user info on each site but that's not what I want -- I want totally separate accounts).

Comment: Actually, I wanted to link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live. Not sure, but this may very be [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live/260206#comment848288_260206

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now that we switched to the "you're logging into the network" model, your options are as follows:

- Different browsers
- Different profiles in the same browser if your browsers supports that sort of thing
- Incognito/private mode in your browser
- Log out to switch accounts

<sub>(Well, it's less of a switch, but now it's global auth that actually works more than the old system did. Same diff, give or take.)</sub>

Comment: Or incognito mode (or equivalent)?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Oh yeah, that too. Added.

Comment: OK, but sad though : (

Comment: Is there a way that I can have an account on a site and _not_ have it listed on my network profile page or otherwise be discoverable? http://stackexchange.com/users/37099/anna-lear?tab=accounts

Comment: @jlarson Not really. You can "hide" a community from your profile, but it's built as a convenience rather than a true privacy feature, so you can't rely on it if complete separation of identities is important to you.

Comment: Hmmm... that makes me sad.  I thought the founders had originally supported the idea of fully controlling your identity.  In my own case I don't have a lot to hide honestly but for others it could be very important, even a safety concern. // Oh well, it seems ok with different browsers